# CosmosDB SQL, insert groupBy results in groups

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In CosmosDB, I can group items like that

```sql
SELECT c.group, COUNT(1) as count
FROM c
GROUP BY c.group
```

On a datastructure like

```json
[
  { key: "a", group: 1 },
  { key: "b", group: 1 },
  { key: "c", group: 1 },
  { key: "d", group: 1 },
  { key: "e", group: 2 },
]
```

I would get

```json
[{group: 1, count: 3}, {group: 2, count: 1}]
```

Is it possible to include a sample, say 3 items, into each group, so I get the following result:

```json
[
  {
    group: 1,
    count: 3,
    sample: [
      { key: "a", group: 1 },
      { key: "b", group: 1 },
      { key: "c", group: 1 }, 
    ]
  },
  {
    group: 2,
    count: 1,
    sample: [
      { key: "b", group: 2 },
    ]
  },
]
```